# is there any options to display infoWindow automatically on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using [GMaps](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) to display a map on my website. It is pretty easy to create a map with an infoWindow. However, the infoWindow only appears when the marker is clicked.

My Javascript:

```
var map;
$(document).ready(function(){
   map = new GMaps({
        div: '#map',
        lat: 11.5671732,
        lng: 104.92592450000006,
        zoom: 15
   });
   map.addMarker ({
       lat: 11.5671732,
       lng: 104.92592450000006,
       infoWindow: {
          content: "<h3>D-Care Dental Clinic</h3><p class='address'>Address: No.26,St.23, <br />Sangkat Chey Chom Nas, Khan Daun Penh, Phnom Penh, Tel: 023 986836/012887601</p>"
       },
   });
});
```

After stackoverflowing, I only see people hard coding using Google map API to achieve this.
So I wonder if there is any option to display infoWindow automatically on page load without clicking on the marker?

[Here's the link to my map page](http://www.dcaredental.com/contact/).

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is a option to do so. If you look in the plugin's sourcecode there is nothing that could do that.

Comment: No, @geocodezip's answer actually solves my problem

Comment: Yep, but that is not what you wanted according to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triggering a click on the marker should work:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map.markers[0], 'click');
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ndkvkgkr/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
$(document).ready(function() {
  map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat: 11.5671732,
    lng: 104.92592450000006,
    zoom: 15
  });
  map.addMarker({
    lat: 11.5671732,
    lng: 104.92592450000006,
    infoWindow: {
      content: "<h3>D-Care Dental Clinic</h3><p class='address'>Address: No.26,St.23, <br />Sangkat Chey Chom Nas, Khan Daun Penh, Phnom Penh, Tel: 023 986836/012887601</p>"
    },
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(map.markers[0], 'click');
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/gmaps.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

infowindow.open(map,marker);

should do the trick.

It will connect better via an example, basically we will simply make infowindow.open(); a part of "initialize" function itself and call "initialize" function on map load.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(28.4387675, 77.5243212); //replace with lan and lat
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: myLatlng
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                    '<p>Add information for info window here</p>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Contact Us'
        });
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Now place this code in  section:

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="height:425px; "> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks kate, hope added example explains it better.